# Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm used PHP-FFMpeg and trying convert mp4 file

ffmpeg failed to execute command

'/var/www/u0738345/data/www/vendor/ffmpeg-git-20230313-amd64-static/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/var/www/u0738345/data/www/vpbot.arpim.ru/123.mp4' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '320k' '-ac' '2' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/var/www/u0738345/data/www/vpbot.arpim.ru/ffmpeg-tmp/ffmpeg-passes64936c460dcc2/pass-64936c460e49b' '/var/www/u0738345/data/www/vpbot.arpim.ru/321.mp4':
Error Output: ffmpeg version N-65014-g7c130d6911-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/u0738345/data/www/vpbot.arpim.ru/123.mp4':
Metadata: major_brand :
mp42 minor_version : 1
compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
creation_time : 2023-06-17T12:41:49.000000Z
Duration: 00:00:26.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1676 kb/s

Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 848x848, 1608 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
Metadata: creation_time : 2023-06-17T12:41:49.000000Z handler_name : Core Media Video vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]

Stream #0:10x2: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
Metadata: creation_time : 2023-06-17T12:41:49.000000Z handler_name : Core Media Audio vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]

Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x6a68ac0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x6a68ac0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX [vost#0:0/libx264 @ 0x6a68600] Error initializing output stream: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x6a53240] Qavg: 42718.570
[aac @ 0x6a53240] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!

Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.